# Filter array of objects and leave only one record of a specific category in the array and leave others as they are

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array of objects. For example:

```
const obj = [
 {category: "Category", value: 1},
 {category: "Category", value: 2},
 {category: "Category", value: 3},
 ...
 {category: "Category1", value: 1},
 {category: "Category1", value: 2},
 {category: "Category1", value: 3},
 ...
 {category: "Category2", value: 1},
 {category: "Category2", value: 2},
 {category: "Category2", value: 3},
];
```

And I need to filter it for this output:

```
const filteredObj = [
 {category: "Category", value: 1},
 {category: "Category", value: 2},
 {category: "Category", value: 3},
 ...
 {category: "Category1", value: 1},
 {category: "Category1", value: 2},
 {category: "Category1", value: 3},
 ...
 {category: "Category2", value: 1},
];
```

Leave all categories as they are, but leave only one record for the "Category2".

Comment: And *which* of the `Category2` records do you want to keep?

Comment: `obj.filter(o => o.category != 'Category2' || o.value == 1)` should do it.

Comment: Why you don't use Array.filter with the condition by category and value fields?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @Bergi Any of them, and value could be anything, only the category matters.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a closure over a counter.

```js
const 
    filterAtZero = count => ({ category }) => category !== 'Category2' || !count++,
    data = [{ category: "Category", value: 1 }, { category: "Category", value: 2 }, { category: "Category", value: 3 }, { category: "Category1", value: 1 }, { category: "Category1", value: 2 }, { category: "Category1", value: 3 }, { category: "Category2", value: 1 }, { category: "Category2", value: 2 }, { category: "Category2", value: 3 }],
    result = data.filter(filterAtZero(0));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The way you've split the IIFE looks like it's passing two arguments to `filter`

Comment: Putting it in one line. Using `let` instead of an IIFE. Or writing `result = (count => data.filter(…))(0);`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
var obj = [
{category: "Category", value: 1},
{category: "Category", value: 2},
{category: "Category", value: 3},
{category: "Category1", value: 1},
{category: "Category1", value: 2},
{category: "Category1", value: 3},

{category: "Category2", value: 1},
{category: "Category2", value: 2},
{category: "Category2", value: 3},
];
let isInclude = false;
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.filter(ele=>{
if(ele.category == "Category2" && !isInclude){
isInclude = true;
return ele;
}
else if(ele.category !== "Category2")
return ele;
}));
```